# How to handle NoSuchElement Exception in Getter Methods of Page Design Pattern

Tags: java, testng, getter-setter, nosuchelementexception

I'm seeing a NoSuchElement exception in the Getter method due to a blank page appearing in my test application.
How can I make sure testing proceeds to the next level after the above failed test.

TestCode:

```
test.pageClick(logger);
test.PageHeaderValidation(logger);
test.editpageClick(logger);
***test.editPageHeaderValidation(logger);*** (this page is appearing blank so Header element is not found - hence NoSuchelement exception in the getter method );
test.switchoutfromIfrane(logger);
```

How can I make sure the test proceeds with the next method instead of stopping at the failed method.

New to the portal, Apologies if this is the not the right space.

Comment: You should rather handle this exception on implementation level not test level and then assert the outcome of the exception handling that you implemented. If there are _expected_ Exceptions thrown you should just write a test that checks for them.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this:

```
try {
  test.editPageHeaderValidation(logger);
} catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
  // Maybe turn some variable to true to show that the exception was caught? 
  // Like: boolean emptyPageHeaderThrows = true;
}
```

Or if you are using JUnit:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;

assertThrows(NoSuchElementException.class, () - > test.editPageHeaderValidation(logger))
```